# SATA/USB-connected drive is sometimes not recognized on rpi

Tags: usb, hard-drive, connection

I use a sata/usb converter to connect a Samsung drive to the rpi.  It is often not recognized at system start.  The drive is recognized without problems when I plug the USB into my ubuntu laptop.  I suspect that the drive takes too long to start.

Currently, I see no udev activity for it in the logs, no special file is created in /dev.  I have tried:

sudo service udev restart

to no avail.  The drive is totally not responding to the rpi at this time, but it has previously done so, sometimes only after reboot.